# login with mobile or email in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

we want to add a functionality where the user can login into our laravel application using their `email address` or using their `mobile`.
We are unable to do the same, there is one way we found, but we are not happy since it is inside vendor folder, which can be easily removed!

*vendor folder path* `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
<?php 

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth; 

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang; 

trait AuthenticatesUsers 
{ 
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins; 


    /** 
     * Show the application's login form. 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function showLoginForm() 
    { 
        return view('auth.login'); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Handle a login request to the application. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function login(Request $request) 
    { 
        $this->validateLogin($request); 
        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle 
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and 
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application. 
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) { 
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request); 
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request); 
        } 

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) { 

           return $this->sendLoginResponse($request); 
        } 
        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts 
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this 
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out. 
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request); 

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Validate the user login request. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return void 
     */ 
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request) 
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [ 
            $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 
        ]); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Attempt to log the user into the application. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return bool 
     */ 
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request) 
    { 
        // return $this->guard()->attempt( 
        //     $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember') 
        // ); 
        if (Auth::attempt([ 
            'mobile' => $request['username'], 
            'password' => $request['password'] 
            ],$request->has('remember')) 
            || Auth::attempt([ 
            'email' => $request['username'], 
            'password' => $request['password'] 
            ],$request->has('remember'))){ 
                return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return array 
     */ 
    protected function credentials(Request $request) 
    {    
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password'); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request) 
    { 
        $request->session()->regenerate(); 

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request); 

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user()) 
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); 
    } 

    /** 
     * The user has been authenticated. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @param  mixed  $user 
     * @return mixed 
     */ 
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) 
    { 
        // 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get the failed login response instance. 
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse 
     */ 
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request) 
    { 
        return redirect()->back() 
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember')) 
            ->withErrors([ 
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'), 
            ]); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller. 
     * 
     * @return string 
     */ 
    public function username() 
    { 
        return 'username'; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Log the user out of the application. 
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function logout(Request $request) 
    { 
        $this->guard()->logout(); 

        $request->session()->flush(); 

        $request->session()->regenerate(); 

        return redirect('/'); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication. 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard 
     */ 
    protected function guard() 
    { 
        return Auth::guard(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a trait, and your Authentication controller uses this trait. So, you can just override the `attemptLogin` method to achieve what you want.

In this case, the logic to determine whether to use a mobile number or email would fall under that method.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you need to, actually, copy the `attemptLogin` method to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`, instead of modifying the vendor files.

It seems you already have some kind of logic going on there. That should handle it.

Comment: can you tell me how, simple example :)

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom trait for AuthenticatesUers.php.

**Step 1) Create a Trait CustomAuthenticatesUsers.php in app/traits folder.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;

trait CustomAuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if(!session()->has('url.intended'))
        {
            session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
        }

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request) 
    { 
        // return $this->guard()->attempt( 
        //     $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember') 
        // ); 
        if (Auth::attempt([ 
            'mobile' => $request['username'], 
            'password' => $request['password'] 
            ],$request->has('remember')) 
            || Auth::attempt([ 
            'email' => $request['username'], 
            'password' => $request['password'] 
            ],$request->has('remember'))){ 
                return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

**Step 2)Add the following Code in LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Traits\CustomAuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use CustomAuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```